# PHP Contact form error with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts

I have a PHP contact form with validation and I want to show the error/success message with jQuery effect.

Thanks!

Comment: and you did not try anything?

Comment: post some code please

Comment: You should not ask for code here! This site is to discus problems that you have encountered or those you cant overcome by yourself or need a better practise or something.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use ajax to post the form data to server and then after server side validation and insertion into database you send back the response to client.

You can use a hidden div to place the response into and then you can make this div visible to show the error or confirmation message.

Comment: That is not very true, one could implement validation rules with jQuery to validate the input data and if valid to allow user to submit the form, otherwise to show messages to point the user in right direction. No downvote because it is an option, not very good one but still..

Comment: ofcourse one can do it but, if you are doing all the validation in client side what if some one build a javascript code that would submit data to your server 4 times in one second? There is always need for server side validation.

Comment: No doubt the data validation at server side is a MUST, but in the current question, the solution would be with jQuery validation client side and server side validation + a bit of filtering and all done.